# How to resolve ERR_NETWORK error when connecting to .NET Web API app hosted on IIS from Android mobile phone using Ionic app?

Tags: reactjs, .net, api, ionic-framework, iis

I have a .NET web API app hosted on an IIS website. I can successfully connect to the API from any other pc on the same network, but I get connection errors from my android mobile phone.

I have an ionic android app as an APK on my android phone. When I hit the API running on the IIS website, it greets me with an ERR_NETWORK error. I also downloaded postman on the mobile phone, and when I try to connect to the API I get the same connection error. When I try to connect to the API from any other PC on my house network, everything works just fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: [Please refer to this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl0IpoS503A) to ensure that the mobile phone and the laptop with wireshark software are in the same network environment to capture packets.